# Firebase Database Structure Review to Review

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r2dN.png)
[image]

My Firebase Structure is below.

```
Review
    -userUid 
        -shopUid
              -ReviewItem(Time, UserNick, ShopName...)
```

I want to make it possible that Review to Review(comment to comment) structure.

ex)

```
user1 Hi.
        -user2 Hello.
        -user3 HI.

    user2 Good
        -user1 Great.
```

Like this.

How to Change Database structure?

I attached firebase.json with comment.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UHpFIhk5gEUIzyqH6mmN2F8o24l4lywc